# Trying to understand the Ruby .chr and .ord methods

Tags: ruby, encoding

I've been working with the Ruby `chr` and `ord` methods recently and there are a few things I don't understand.

My current project involves converting individual characters to and from ordinal values.  As I understand it, if I have a string with an individual character like "A" and I call `ord` on it I get its position on the ASCII table which is 65.  Calling the inverse, `65.chr` gives me the character value "A",  so this tells me that Ruby has a collection somewhere of ordered character values, and it can use this collection to give me the position of a specific character, or the character at a specific position.  I may be wrong on this, please correct me if I am.

Now I also understand that Ruby's default character encoding uses UTF-8 so it can work with thousands of possible characters.  Thus if I ask it for something like this:

```
'好'.ord
```

I get the position of that character which is 22909.  However, if I call `chr` on that value:

```
22909.chr
```

I get "RangeError: 22909 out of char range."  I'm only able to get `char` to work on values up to 255 which is extended ASCII.  So my questions are:

- Why does Ruby seem to be getting values for `chr` from the extended ASCII character set but `ord` from UTF-8?
- Is there any way to tell Ruby to use different encodings when it uses these methods?  For instance, tell it to use ASCII-8BIT encoding instead of whatever it's defaulting to?
- If it is possible to change the default encoding, is there any way of getting the total number of characters available in the set being used?

Comment: http://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/chr mentions you can use something like ``22909.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)``. Encoding also has ``Encoding::ASCII_8BIT`` if you want to use that instead.

Comment: @NabeelAmjad You should post that as an answer.

Comment: This is very helpful, I hadn't seen that and this gets me a long way to where I'm going.  Now, the only thing I'm missing is a simple way to get the number of characters availabe for a specific encoding.  For instance ASCII_8BIT has 256 characters, UTF_8 about 1.1 million, ect.  And yes, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Posted as an answer, I'm not sure on how to get the number of characters available though, had a look but couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and the linked pages. The links will be very useful and help you understand how to approach asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [`Integer#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-chr) you can use the following to force the encoding to be UTF_8.

```
22909.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
#=> "好"
```

To list all available encoding names

```
Encoding.name_list
#=> ["ASCII-8BIT", "UTF-8", "US-ASCII", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-16LE", "UTF-32BE", "UTF-32LE", "UTF-16", "UTF-32", ...]
```

A hacky way to get the maximum number of characters

```
2000000.times.reduce(0) do |x, i|
  begin
    i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
    x += 1
  rescue
  end

  x
end
#=> 1112064
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  I was afraid I'd have to try something like that to get the max character number.  Not pretty, but we work with what we have, right?

Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

After tooling around with this for a while, I realized that I could get the max number of characters for each encoding by running a binary search to find the highest value that doesn't throw a RangeError.

```
def get_highest_value(set)
  max = 10000000000
  min = 0
  guess = 5000000000

  while true
    begin guess.chr(set)
      if (min > max)
        return max
      else
        min = guess + 1
        guess = (max + min) / 2
      end
    rescue
      if min > max
        return max
      else
        max = guess - 1
        guess = (max + min) / 2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The value input to the method is the name of the encoding being checked.